# Inheritance between persisted models in loopback

Tags: javascript, inheritance, loopbackjs

I'm actually trying to use loopback, and I wonder if it's possible to define a complex model architecture using inheritance like we can do with `Hibernate` ([Chapter 9. Inheritance mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)).

For example, how can I define an abstract class `Vehicle`, a class `Car` that extends `Vehicle` and a class `Truck` that extends `Vehicle` too ?

Thank you

Comment: There are no "abstract" classes like Hibernate has. I haven't seen anyone doing anything like that in LoopBack or in Node at all really.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after some researches, if you use an sql database there is some posibilities :

- create those models in loopback
- create those tables in postgresql (for example)
- create a view in postgres that make wrapping of everything
- create a model in loopback binded to sql view

Several avantages

- Inheritance mapping working
- Better performances than the loopback embedded orm